# How to play Video coming in HTML String in IONIC 4

Tags: angular, ionic4, angular-dom-sanitizer

I've HTML string coming from API and inside HTML String I am getting youtube video into `<iFrame></iFrame>`

I want to display this video along with HTML.

```
export class BlogDetailsPage implements OnInit {
  detail = {};
  constructor(public domSanitizer: DomSanitizer, private ms: MasterService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    var id = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
    this.ms.present();
    this.ms.getblogDetail(id).subscribe(res => {
      this.detail = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(res.content.rendered);
      console.log(this.detail);
      this.ms.dismiss();
    });
  }
}
```

In HTML I display string by following code

```
{{detail}}
<div class="blog-box" *ngIf="detail.content != undefined" [innerHTML]="detail">
</div>
```

Output
[image]

I am unable to display HTML either Video.

Comment: Have you tried without `{{detail}}` - isn't that what's triggering the error and then not making it as far as the `[innerHTML]` which I thought was correct?

Comment: innerHTML is not showing anything

Comment: added my thoughts as an answer instead

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a comment / guess but I needed the formatting and space to explain.

What I meant was remove the `{{detail}}` because I think that is causing your error.

Also, now I type this, it seems like you are using two different structures - `detail.content` in the if and then trying to display `detail` in the innerHTML.

Combining both of these ideas, try changing from this:

```
{{detail}}
<div class="blog-box" *ngIf="detail.content != undefined" [innerHTML]="detail">
</div>
```

To this:

```
<div class="blog-box" *ngIf="detail.content != undefined" [innerHTML]="detail.content">
</div>
```